# Increment count

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, calculated-column-formula

I have an SPO list where I want to do an event tracker. It will track if an instance happens it increments by one, and we keep tracking for a year. At the end of the year the tracker reset to 0, and then increments again by adding one to the list of events every time a new event is created. Any suggestions? I have tried a couple of things with formulas but cant't seem to get it right, because I can't call the last row of items count or value.

Comment: Hir you have similar question [https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228036/calculated-field-formula-to-create-an-incremental-number][1]

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend using MS Flow or Workflow to do this. You can use a certain column/item to hold the records.

The process is also similar. Add a trigger occurs when a new list item is created. Use if condition to check if the desired event occurs. Get the recorded value. Then update a certain column which holds the records. A new if condition will check if it is the end of the year. If yes, reset the counter.